# Renombrar un grupo de archivos

Tags: linux

Trabajo con Debian. He partido son split un archivo de 75 GB en 1000 trozos de 75 MB y me los ha renombrado mal a partir del trozo 90, y tengo que solucionar ese problema

A partir del trozo archivo_89, no se el motivo, ha seguido con el archivo_9000 en vez del archivo_90 que es el que le correspondía, y a partir de ahí ha seguido archivo_9001, archivo_9002 ...

Total que tengo que renombrar desde el archivo_9000 hasta el final y pasar los nombres a archivo_90 hasta el final, pero sin que pierdan el orden que tienen.

Estoy intentando hacerlo con el comando rename, pero no encuentro una solución viable

Gracias

Comment: escribe lo que has intentado

Comment: ¿Cómo aparecen los archivos que debieran ser los de 100 y los de 900?

Comment: pues concretamente el que debería ser 100 aparece como 9010 y así consecutivamente

Answer (score 1):

Seria preferible utilizar algo como `rename`. En mi caso no se utilizarlo, asi que otra forma de hacer esto seria lo siguiente:

1. Ejecutas un bucle por cada uno de los archivos que empiezan por archivo_9. Esto lo hago porque los primeros 89 estan correctos, y dado que lo has hecho hasta 1000, no superaran los 9900... por lo que los incorrectos (en principio) son todos los que tengan un 9 en su nombre.
2. cortamos el numero del archivo. Aqui he supuesto que tus archivos tienen como nombre `archivo_XXXX.file`, si no es asi tendras que definir de otra manera como obtener dicha parte numerica.
3. el numero correcto de ese archivo deberia ser `numero - 9000 + 90` (quitamos el desplazamiento del 9000 erroneo, y ponemos el 90, que seria el primer numero correcto)
4. por ultimo, puedes renombrar ese archivo con el nuevo numero.

Te dejo un ejemplo en shell. Deberias ajustarlo para tu caso en concreto. He comentado la linea de cambio del archivo `mv` para que veas primero el nuevo nombre del archivo a ver si queda correcto.

```
for file in $(ls archivo_9*); do 
  a=$(echo $file |cut -d_ -f2 | cut -d. -f1); 
  correcto=`expr $a - 9000 + 90` ; 
  rem mv $file archivo_$correcto.file; 
  echo "archivo_$correcto.ext";
done
```

Answer (score 1):

En Debian, deberias tener el `rename` (`perl-rename`, pero simplemente `rename` en Debian) instalado. Sino, lo puedes instalar con `sudo apt install rename`. Después, haz:

```
rename -n 's/_(\d+)/_ . sprintf($1 - 8910)/e' archivo_9???
```

Con el `-n` simplemente va a imprimir lo que haría pero sin hacerlo. Si ves que funciona bien, quita el `-n` y vuelve a ejecutar el comando.

#### Explicación

El `rename` es un script Perl que ejecuta los que le dices a cada fichero de entrada. Aquí, le decimos de buscar todos los números que son después de un `_` (`_\d+`), y reemplazarlos con ellos mismos menos 8910. El `archivo_9???` se convertirá en la lista de ficheros cuyo nombre empieza con `archivo_9` y tiene 3 mas caracteres. El `s/foo/bar/` reemplazará el `foo` con `bar`. Aquí, buscamos uno o mas números después de un `_` y lo reemplazamos con el mismo numero menos 8910.

---

Si no quieres o no puedes usar el `rename`, lo puedes también hacer manualmente:

```
for f in archivo_9???; do 
    n=${f//archivo_}; 
    echo "mv $f archivo_$((n-8910))"; 
done
```

Aquí también, si ves que funciona bien, quita el echo:

```
for f in archivo_9???; do 
    n="${f//archivo_}"; 
    mv "$f" archivo_"$((n-8910))" 
done
```

Comment: esto funcionaria si los archivos tienen extension??? quiero decir, el `${f//archivo_}` recorta el valor numerico?

Comment: @Jakala no, esto asume que los nombres son tal como dice la pregunta: `archivo_` y números. Si tienen extensiones cambia la cosa. Pero el `split` no pone extensiones por defecto y la pregunta dice que no tienen, que es lo normal en Linux, entonces no me preocupé por ellos.

Comment: no, si no es por el caso en concreto. Lo decia por si es posible cambiarlo en caso de tener extension. Mas que nada porque no lo conocia y me parece una forma muy buena de hacer el split. Entiendo que seria utilizar dos split (uno para la parte anterior y otro para la posterior)

Comment: @Jakala si, son super utiles estas funciones de manipulación de strings en el shell. Mira: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html. Por las extensiones, puedes hacer algo tipo `f="archivo_100.txt; num=${f//archivo_}; num=${num%.*}; echo $num` o, si ya sabes la extension, `f="archivo_100.txt; num=$(basename "${f//archivo_}" .txt); echo $num`.